# How to change the locomotive status from moving in a spline to moving in the next spline when it meets the next rail?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, beziers, splines

I want to make a train that can move in a curve. I have downloaded a Train Spline Walker unity package.
That package can generate a spline, and the train's locomotive will move in the spline with a flexible direction and rotation. It'll start by the 1st point of the Bézier spline and stop at the last point. I read the code and I'm pretty sure that those points are called `ControlPoint`s.

The problem is that I want the train to also be able to move in a line. Because you know, trains in reality can move in a line and also along curves.

The rails (including 2 types: Rail type A is a straight line and rail type B is a curve) can be auto-generated to fit geometrical rules.

I want to attach the Bézier spline to a rail type B (curve) so that each time the locomotive collides with the collision point (which is an empty object I make) of the type B rails, it will follow a script and move along that Bezier spline.

Through a comment suggestion, i have changed the straight line into curve 0 degree, now im trying to change the locomotive from moving a spline into the next spline.

But it didn't work.

Can anyone suggest how to change the locomotive status from moving in a spline to moving in the next spline when it meets the next rail?

This is the link to the code i downloaded:
https://onlinegdb.com/gjpF5Snjq

Comment: With only that much information, you won't get a good answer. We don't know which spline train asset you use, how it works or what you did so far. The question should contain a minimal working scene or at least the code that is relevant

Comment: A straight line is just a cubic Bézier curve with its middle two control points placed ⅓ and ⅔ of the way along the line between the start/end anchor points. So you could implement both straight line rail segments and curved segments with Béziers, using the same code for all rail following, if switching between two rail behaviours is what's giving you trouble.

Comment: My gratitude to you first, i have thought about implementing both of them as Bezier, the problem is, when the locomotive moves in the spline of straight rail has travel to the end point of the spline, i want it to move to the next spline.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, really sorry for making confusions.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/gjpF5Snjq

Comment: This is my downloaded code, i attached the MoveInSpline script to the locomotive and created a spline with BezierSpline script.

Comment: We won't visit code hosted in external links. Make sure everything needed to reproduce your problem is included in the body of your question post.

Comment: Sorry i mean i just want to combine 2 spline, you know that spline have p0,p1,p2,p3 which p0 is startpoint and p3 is the end point, i think i can connect 2 spline by make spline1.p3 become spline2.p0 but i dont know how to do that.